# Should I translate academic designations given after a name (earned in English) into French?

Tags: traduction, société, éducation

In English, people's names are sometimes stated with an academic designation (basically, a degree) in their name: “John Smith, Ph.D.”.
When adding an academic designation after a name, should the abbreviation be translated into French if the document in which it appears is in French? Specifically, should the E in “B.Ed.” (Bachelor of Education, earned in English) have the acute accent (*accent aigu*) added to it?

Comment: Bachelor of Education, like B.Sc. means Bachelor of Science.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only if the title has an official translation. For example, in that case the title exists in French (in Quebec at least): “*Bachelier ès Éducation*”. The acronym becomes “*B.Éd.*”.

In the case the title does not have a translation (which I cannot find examples of), I would not change it.

Answer (score 1):

1- "ès" est un raccourci pour "en les" ; comme pourrait-il être suivi d'un singulier ?

2- La question est singulièrement complexe pour les titres non universitaires, qui eux ont à peu près des équivalents (certains trompeurs : B.S. est Bachelor in Surgery, et LL.D. Legum Doctor).
Mais comment traduire (sans expliquer par une périphrase) : "The Right Honorable John Smith, D.S.O., C.V.O., M.O.H." ?

Answer (score 1):

In French, we just usually don’t put qualifications behind names. The only exception I can think of is on business card, but then again abbreviation are rare : if you need to do it, just write the whole thing down.